# firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

It's my first time using firebase and I'm trying to change the persistence but getting the above error.  Here's the code I'm using.  I've left out the config settings for brevity:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

The examples on the firebase website ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)) dont do anything different to what I'm doing, why can't I pass firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION without getting an error?

If I skip that section and just call

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
```

then I am sucessfully signed in, so its not as though I'm unable to contact firebase.  Is there some sort of back end setup I have to do first?  Or something else I need to call?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firebase JS?

Comment: Oh how embarrassing, that's it!!  I got the code from the firechat site and their demo was only including 3.3.0.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad it is not a bug :)